# MongoDB Schema using Deno or Rust

Tags: mongodb, rust, database-schema, deno

I'm trying to create a schema in MongoDB using deno_mongo for deno and MongoDB rust dive for rust but I cannot figure out if it is possible.

I want to execute something similar to this in Mongo CLI

```
db.createCollection('test',{ 
  validator: { 
    $jsonSchema: { 
    bsonType: 'object', 
    required:['field1', 'field2'], 
    properties:{ 
      field1: { 
        bsonType:'string', 
        description:'enter field1'
      }, 
      field2: { 
        bsonType:'string', 
        description:'enter field2'
      }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**deno_mongo** does not support `createCollection` *yet* (28 September 2020). As Deno evolves there is most certainly going to be options for this but at not yet at the moment.

I tried to find a way to get the name of the database in use, but actually you can not even do that.  With javascript you can only get the `db["name"]` property but that does not confirm the name from MongoDB.  It is the same with `createCollection`.

There is not a `createCollection` command but there is [`db.runCommand() create`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/create/#dbcmd.create) which is not supported yet.

Also there is a way to run scripts in [MongoDB shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) which then manipulates your database as you wish.